# When did Yaakov's stones become one?

Tags: midrash, vayeitzei

The beginning of *Vayetze* describes *Yaakov*'s going to sleep with a stone or stones at his head. I've heard that a *midrash* says that various stones argued over which of them would be under his head, and that God merged them into one stone that could be under *Yaakov*'s head. I can think of three scenarios; which occurred?

1. *Yaakov* put them all at his head and went to sleep. They got merged afterward.
2. *Yaakov* put them all down for his head, including one that his head would actually rest on. They argued over which should be under his head, and got merged. Then he went to bed.
3. *Yaakov* went looking for a stone to put his head on. A bunch of stones wanted to be chosen, argued, and got merged, and *Yaakov* chose the resulting stone.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79540

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *midrash* appears in the *Bavli*, *Chulin* 91 *amud* 2. (*Midrash Raba* 68 discusses the stones' merging, but not their argument.)

- *Rashi* on *Chumash* and *Maharsha* on *Chulin* say that *Yaakov* made a sort of headrest out of the stones, including a stone for under his head and some more for around his head, and then the stones argued. That would accord with either of the **first two** of the three options in the question. The *L'vush* on *Rashi* says that *Yaakov* made the headrest, "and, afterward, they became one stone via a miracle that night", which sounds to me like the transformation happened after *Yaakov* had gone to bed, the **first** option in the question.
- The *Ben Y'hoyada* on *Chulin* says that *Yaakov* chose to rest his head on the merged stone. That would accord with either of the **last two** of the three options in the questions.

So I think it's a matter of dispute.