# The Stones of Yaakov

Tags: midrash, avot-patriarch-fathers, vayeitzei, literalism, jacob

the gemora in Chulin 91b comments on the pasuk in parsha vayetzei

> Rabbi Yitzchak said: This tells us that all the stones gathered
>   themselves together into one place and each one said: 'Upon me shall
>   this righteous man rest his head'. Thereupon all [the stones], a Tanna
>   taught, were merged into one.

Is this meant to be taken literally?  Does this mean inanimate objects have some sort of awareness?

I am especially interested in the view that it is literal and that these rocks were real as the Mesilat Yesharim writes in [ch.26](http://dafyomireview.com/mesilat.php?d=29)  "in this way was all use they made of the things of this world. Since they were clinging to God's holiness it was an elevation and an enhancement for that thing which merited to be of use to a Tzadik. Our sages already referred to the matter of the "stones at the place" which Yaakov took and put under his head.."

Comment: The Midrash may be literal, but inanimate objects may lack consciousness. Make sure to avoid false dichotomies.

Comment: @mevaqesh did not mean to exclude that possibility

Answer (score 3):

The Meiri suggests a non-literal interpretation of the Midrash in his introduction to Beit HaBehira:

> וכן דרכי התורה **יודיעו הטוב והרע והיודעיו ישוב בנקל מחטאיו או ישמור עצמו מתחלתו שלא לעשותם**...**שאם יחייבוהו משפטי מערכת תולדתו באחת מן התכונות הרעות דרכי התורה יגדרוהו וישמרוהו מצוק העתים**...שלא יזיקו לו המונעים המזגיים כלל אבל יכנעו לו לכל רצונו **והוא אצלי גם כן ענין הסרת לב האבן ונתינת לב בשר במקומו וזאת הכונה אצלי במה שרמזו במדרשות על שלמות יעקב אבינו ושבהיותו בדרך היו לו מונעים רבים מן הצרות והטרדות** כמו שנודע מהעוני ומן ענוי הדרך...ואמר ש**בעת התבודדו ועלותו במדרגה הנכבדת נהפך לבב כל מונע ונכנע לרצונו ואמר עלי יניח צדיק זה ראשו** עד שהתאחדו כל המונעים ושבו אצלו להפך טבעם **עד שנכנעו לכונתו והתחברו בלב אחד תחת מראשותיו להכנע מתחת לראשו**

That is, the stones in the Midrash are a metaphor for Ya'akov's internal inclinations which would normally make it very difficult to serve God properly in such circumstances as arduous travel. Nevertheless, God rewarded him with divine assistance and made his otherwise negative inclinations all unite under him to serve him.

Comment: [Same guy](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/729/sheidim-are-they-fact-or-fiction/57115#comment196558_57115)?